# Using onChange Event in ASP.NET combined with Bootstrap

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, onchange

I wanna create two textareas.
The first textarea should used by the user.
Every time the user will change the textarea value it should be checked
and given out in another textarea.
I tried to add `runat="server"` and `onChange="fTextChanged"` in the bootrstrap
textarea control.
This is my usercontrol:

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="ToTranslate">Text to translate:</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" runat="server" onChange="fTextChanged" rows="5" id="ToTranslate"></textarea>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="TranslatedText">Translated text:</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" runat="server" rows="5" id="TranslatedText"></textarea>
 </div> 
</div>
```

And this is my CodeBehind:

```
public void fTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Content = ToTranslate.Value;
    TranslatedText.Value = Content;
}
```

I tried to debug it, but it appears that the compiler(Website?) ignore the function.
My VS2017 dont stop at the breakpoint:

```
Content = ToTranslate.Value;
```

I'm new in the web programming at all, I'm just used to C#, C++, and LabView.
I hope you nice guys can help me.

Kind regards!

**EDIT:**
Changing:

```
<textarea class="form-control" runat="server" onChange="fTextChanged" rows="5" id="ToTranslate"></textarea>
```

To:

```
<asp:TextBox class="form-control" ID="ToTranslate" runat="server" OnTextChanged="fTextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5"></asp:TextBox>
```

Worked pretty well.

Comment: "but it appears that I ignore the function"  i don't understand thi8s

Comment: I think he means the function never gets hit

Comment: Yeah, I never enter it@DNKROZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this on client side you would use `onchange` event with javascript code as follows

```js
function KeyUp()
{
        var ToTranslate = document.getElementById("ToTranslate");
        var s = ToTranslate.value;
    
        var TranslatedText = document.getElementById("TranslatedText");
        TranslatedText.innerText = ""+s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ToTranslate">Text to translate:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" runat="server" rows="5"  id="ToTranslate" onKeyPress="KeyUp()" onKeyUp="KeyUp()"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="TranslatedText">Translated text:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" runat="server" rows="5"  id="TranslatedText"></textarea>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

If you should use a **server-side code** however, then I would transform html control to asp.net control as follows as you could only find server-side events on asp.net controls (not very sure, I will check it);

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ToTranslate" runat="server" OnTextChanged="fTextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static"  TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I think the property is `TextChanged` rather than `OnTextChanged`

Comment: I confirm, it is `OnTextChanged`

Comment: My bad you're right, `OnTextChanged` fires the `TextChanged` event

Comment: Is there a way to use Bootstrap styles with asp.net controls or have I to go with javascript?

Comment: You can always use bootstrap, styling is irrelevant here, if you think you can handle your controls with data on client side, then go ahead with javascript event (if they are simple like type checking, number limit etc)

Comment: @k.Lennartz btw, I added bootstrap libs to the code in case you hesitated that styling has gone.

Comment: where do I have to implement the javascript function above or below the div ?

Comment: For this, it really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the property `AutoPostBack="True"` to your `textarea`

`AutoPostBack` specifies whether an automatic postback to the server will occur when the control loses focus. In your case, a postback was not occurring, therefore your server side method wasn't being hit.

Personally I'd stick to client side and use JavaScript for something like this, but each to their own!

**edit**

Try using an `asp:TextBox` instead

```
<asp:TextBox id="ToTranslate" OnTextChanged="fTextChanged" TextMode="multiline" Columns="50" Rows="5" runat="server" />
```

Comment: I tried it with adding the property, but it didnt work :(
I didnt use Javascript before and the given method is just a test, so the code in it will be a little more complicate